# Fractal patterns on water

Tags: home-experiment, crystal-structure, identification

I stored water in a bucket (of aluminium probably), and some random fractal-like patterns are formed on the water:

[image]

See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrA9A.jpg) for some more pictures.

Why this happened?

I'm unable to reproduce it. How can I reproduce it ?

Comment: Cross posted from physics SE (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/352377/fractal-patterns-on-water)

Comment: The carbonates precipitate that appears after boiling due to water hardness would often form on the surface (instead of bottom) and look just like that. Others sources seem less probable, though not impossible. As to its shape, it is explained in the answer on Phys.SE.